# SIP servlet container

Tags: glassfish, sip-servlet

Does GlassFish 4.0 server act as a SIP servlet container? I googled but could not find a answer. It may be obvious but I could not figure it out. I am new to Java EE.

I have got a legacy prototype implementation to work with. It uses Java SIP servlet. It's a Netbeans project. It does not have any setup documentation. So I don't know which server I should use.

I installed Netbeans IDE 8.0 with Java EE 7 and GlassFish server 4.0. I thought I would start learning to use SIP servlet by following [Oracle's SIP Servlet Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19502-01/821-0203/gflts/index.html). In that tutorial, "Communication Server" is recommended in "Required Software" section. When I googled to download this, I found [Oracle Communications Converged Application Server](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/communications/unified-communications/converged-application-server/overview/index.html) which was not free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use GlassFish for SIP servlets, I'm not aware of any implementation working with it. But you can use [Mobicents](https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets), built on top of Tomcat or JBoss.

Comment: I also think so. I think the legacy Netbeans project that I got used Sailfins SIP servlet container. Sailfins was discontinued a long time ago. Anyway, I later worked with a sample project from Mobicents. It's cool!